# creating button in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button

I send the parameters to the server and it responses me with an object of array.
I get it and use the `JSON.stringify` function and then `JSON.parse`.
When I assign the button in the body it works properly though it isn't placed correctly in the html. If I assign to the iteration `id` it has an error.
What should I do to handle the problem and have a click event to delete the current item and delete it.
Here is my code:

```
<script>
var param={user_id: localStorage.getItem('user_id')};
getmyItems(param,function(data){
    var mtItem=JSON.stringify(data);
    myItem=JSON.parse(mtItem);
    console.log(myItem);
    var Item=document.getElementById('myItems');
    var buffer="";
    for(var i=0;i<myItem.results.length;i++){

        buffer +='<div class="row">';
            buffer +='<div class="col-md-12">';
                buffer +='<img src="'+myItem.results[i].images+'"/>';
            buffer +='</div>';
        buffer +='</div>';
        buffer +='<div class="row">';
            buffer +='<div class="col-md-4">';
                buffer +='Created on:'+myItem.results[i].creation_date;
            buffer +='</div>';
            buffer +='<div class="col-md-4">';
                buffer +='incident_date:'+myItem.results[i].item_date;
            buffer +='</div>';
            buffer += '<div class="col-md-4">';
                buffer +='approval_date:'+myItem.results[i].approved_date;
            buffer +='</div>';
        buffer +='</div>';
        buffer+='<div class="row">';
            buffer+='<div class="col-md-12">';
                buffer+='Title: '+myItem.results[i].title;
            buffer+='</div>';
        buffer+='</div>';
        buffer+='<div class="row" id="'+i+'">';
            var btn=document.createElement('input');
            btn.setAttribute('type','button');
            btn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-danger');
            btn.value="Delete";
            btn.onclick=(function (i){
                return function(){
                    doDelete(myItem.results[i].item_id);
                };
                })(i);

            document.getElementById('i').appendChild(btn);

        buffer+='</div><hr/>';
    }
    Item.innerHTML=buffer;
});

function doDelete(s){
        var param={
            user_id: localStorage.getItem('user_id'),
            session: sessionStorage.getItem('session'),
            item_id: s
        };
        deleteItem(param, function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: I guess you should remove quotes from `document.getElementById('i').appendChild(btn);` first

Comment: without comma or with comma it say:
"Uncaught TypeError. can not read the property 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: @RayonDabre , I mean when I remove quotes the debugger says:
'Uncaught TypeError . can not read property appendChild of null'.
it is written in console.log

Comment: You are mixing up things.. You have not appended `buffer` in the `DOM` and you are trying to append another element which does not exist in DOM..

Comment: @RayonDabre ,how can I have a loop that creates dynamically buttons when the user click on the specific button , `onclick` event fires. but if i add the `btn` like this `document.body.appendChild('i')` it works but its not in the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, In your case, you are trying to access the element which is not there in the `DOM`

Instead of creating `buffer` and setting `innerHTML` at the end of the loop, create `div` element and set the `buffer` element as `innerHTML` of created `div` element.
`appendChild` the `buffer` element inside `for-loop` and after that, you can access the element having `id` as value of variable `i`

Try this:

```js
var myItem = {
  success: true,
  error_cod: 0,
  results: [{
    title: "flood",
    creation_date: "2016/01/01"
  }, {
    title: "earthquake",
    creation_date: "2016/01/05"
  }]
};
var Item = document.getElementById('myItems');
for (var i = 0; i < myItem.results.length; i++) {
  var buffer = "";
  buffer += '<div><div class="row">';
  buffer += '<div class="col-md-12">';
  buffer += '<img src="' + myItem.results[i].title + '"/>';
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '<div class="row">';
  buffer += '<div class="col-md-4">';
  buffer += 'Created on:' + myItem.results[i].creation_date;
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '<div class="col-md-4">';
  buffer += 'incident_date:' + myItem.results[i].creation_date;
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '<div class="col-md-4">';
  buffer += 'approval_date:' + myItem.results[i].creation_date;
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '<div class="row">';
  buffer += '<div class="col-md-12">';
  buffer += 'Title: ' + myItem.results[i].title;
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '</div>';
  buffer += '<div class="row" id="' + i + '">';
  buffer += '</div><hr/></div>';
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = buffer;
  var elem = div.firstChild;
  Item.appendChild(elem);
  var btn = document.createElement('input');
  btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');
  btn.value = "Delete";
  btn.onclick = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      doDelete(myItem.results[i].creation_date);
    };
  })(i);
  document.getElementById(i).appendChild(btn);
}

function doDelete(s) {
  alert(s);
}
```

```html
<div id="myItems"></div>
```

Comment: sorry. I bring my code here.
`var myItem={success:true, error_cod:0,results:[title:"flood",creation_date:"2016/01/01"],[title:"earthquake",creation_date:"2016/01/05"]};` 
other code is on the top of page. if i bind the `btn` to `document.body.appendChild('id');` it works and it has no error in `console.log `, but if I use `document.getElementById('i')`, on both cases , `console.log` shows me **Uncaught TypeError can not read property appendChild of null**

Comment: that's all my code. `getmyItems` is an object that I receive  from server. it contains attributes like i mentioned in the latest comment. the main code is mentioned at the top of the page. are you sure that code you suggested me fine and works?

Comment: I tested your code 1 hrs ago and I said that has an error like before in `console.log`. I don't know where is the problem?

Comment: You will never get the answer if your question is incomplete.. Share [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or any demo which could be executed..`getmyItems` is not defined..How will one go ahead ?

Comment: Dear, it is doesn't concern the getmyItems. that's just a function that runs my request to bring me 'myItems object' and that works correctly .it is related to `  var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = buffer;
    var elem = div.firstChild;
    Item.appendChild(elem);
` and so ....

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem with a little change. I comment the lines that Rayon provided.
it works nicely.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = buffer;
//var elem = div.firstChild;
Item.appendChild(div);
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');
btn.value = "Delete";
btn.onclick = (function(i) {
  return function() {
    doDelete(myItem.results[i].item_id);
  };
})(i);
Item.appendChild(btn);
//document.getElementById(i).appendChild(btn);
```